# Determining whether a vector belongs in $V=\text{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3).$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $v_1=(1,1,0,3), v_2=(1,2,1,1)$ and $v_3=(0,2,1,0)$ be vectors of $\Bbb{R^4}$ and $V=\text{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3).$ Determine if $v=(5,7,8,0)$ belongs in $V$.

So I would need to reduce the following matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}v_1 && v_2&&v_3 \mid v \end{bmatrix}.$$

However this matrix seems to be inconsistent so in conclusion $v \notin V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work. Or you can compute the determinant of the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 7 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 8 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$Since it is not $0$ (actually, it is $-13$), the four vectors are linearly independent and therefore $v$ is not a linear combination of the other three.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

$v\in\textrm{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ means there exist $x,y,z$ such that
$$
xv_1+yv_2+zv_3=v\tag{1}
$$
In other words, the linear system $AX=v^T$, where $A=[v_1^T v_2^T v_3^T]$ has a solution $X=(x,y,z)^T$.

The [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) $[A\mid v^T]$ being inconsistent means that (1) has no solution and thus $$
v\not\in\textrm{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3).$$